# Replaced toilet valve & tube, turning water back on rumbles

Tags: water, toilet

I replaced all the parts in my toilet, and now when I go to turn my water back on (not the main valve, but the toilet valve) the pipeline starts to rumble/shake a lot about halfway on. I then turn it back off.

Is this normal? Should I continue to turn it on all the way?

Comment: Mr Getterdun has got it right, give him the kudo on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, slowly. There's air in the line making the noise. It will dissipate if you slowly turn the water back on.